# Largest Product in a Series (Project Euler #8)

Tags: c++

I want to solve project Euler problem #8, and I wanted to try doing the largest product of 4 consecutive digits first before I proceed to solve the 13 digit problem (I suppose it will be solved in the same way?), and I tried the following code, but it gives me a big number, not the correct answer which is supposed to be 5832, it gives me 10370808 , and I can't figure out why, could anyone please help me? Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main(){
std::vector<int>store(1000);
std::string numbers = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
 int a = 0;
 int b = 1;
 int c = 2;
 int d = 3;
 int z = 0;
while (d <= 1000){
    z = numbers[a] * numbers[b] * numbers[c] * numbers[d];
    store.push_back(z);
    a++;
    b++;
    c++;
    d++;


}

    std::cout << *std::max_element(store.begin(), store.end()) << std::endl;

}
```

EDIT:The problem is that I have to find the largest product of 13 consecutive digits in the series, sorry for forgetting to write it at first.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What is 'project Euler problem #8'?

Comment: Note that you should totally skip over runs of integers that have 0 in them.  Also, these online coding sites have questions that are designed to reject naive solutions due to time out being reached.  So don't be surprised if your solution (if you ever do get it to work) gets timed out or rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numbers` is a `std::string`, and each element is a `char`. To convert a numeric `char` (`'0'`..`'9'`) to an actual integer value (`0`..`9`) you need to subtract `'0'`:

```
int na = numbers[a] - '0';
int nb = numbers[b] - '0';
int nc = numbers[c] - '0';
int nd = numbers[d] - '0';

z = na * nb * nc * nd;
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that `numbers[a]` does not give you a integer but instead gives you a character representing that integer.  So for your example the first time you call `numbers[a]` it is `'7'` not `7`.  `'7'` can be converted to a `int` and it will have the values of the character code that it has in the character set. In ASCII that would be 37.  What you need to do is subtract `'0'` from the character to convert it to an int.  So if you do that the code would look like

```
z = (numbers[a] - '0') * (numbers[b] - '0')  * (numbers[c] - '0')  * (numbers[d] - '0');
```

This works be because `'7'` is guaranteed to have a character code that is 7 grater than `'0'` in all character sets used by c++.